# C++ - How do I assign the data from a file to several variable

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream, formatted-input

I have create a .txt file, which contain a list of product name, description and quantity.
For example, like:

`100 Plus , Sports Drink , 12
 Sprite , Citrus Drink , 5
 Dutch Lady, Milk, 8`

I want to assign these information to three variable, which is `string name`, `string description`, and `int quantity`

I have tried to use something like `while(product  >> name >> description >> quantity)`, but it only works if it contain only single words and without the comma, but not for string with multiple words.

This is my code.

```
#include <string>
include <fstream>
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string name, description;
int quantity;
fstream product("product.txt");

string c_name[5],c_description[5];
int c_quantity[5];
int i=0;

while(product  >> name >> description >> quantity)
{

    cout<<i<<" Name= "<<name<<", Description= "<< description <<" , Quantity= " <<quantity<<"\n";
    c_name[i] = name;
    c_description[i] = description;
    c_quantity[i] = quantity;
    i++;
}

cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl<<endl;

for(i=0;i<5;i++) //to display the variables
{
    cout<<i+1<<" "<<c_name[i]<<endl;
    cout<<i+1<<" "<<c_description[i]<<endl;
    cout<<i+1<<" "<<c_quantity[i]<<endl<<endl;
}

product.close();
return 0;
}
```

May I know how can I do this?
And if possible i'd like to stick with some simple header files only.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What you need is call "parsing" or "tokenizing" : read a line and then use some algorithm to decompose it into the pieces you want. Your parsing is not so difficult because your data format use commas as separators, I can suggest you to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You may consider [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline) which allows for a delimiter to be used:

```
while ( getline(getline (product, name, ','), description, ',') >> quantity)
```

Just be aware that you may have to remove white spaces at the beining of `description` and  `name`, as `>>` was doing it before. Alternatively you may also opt for adding `product.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');` at the end of your loop block, to make sure that the last newline behind quantity is removed before the nex getline is performed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use stream `>>` operator because as you found it stops at first whitespace.

You need to read one line at a time with

```
std::string line;
std::getline(product, line);
```

and the look for commas with `std::string::find` and extract the parts you need with `std::string::substr`.